# How to display current date in datepicker

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Using c# and silverlight

I want to display a current date in datepicker

Control Code

```
<sdk:DatePicker Name="cAccCreditDate"
                Margin="10,0,0,0"
                DisplayDate="12/12/2014"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
 Width="120" Height="23" />
```

Tried in c#

```
cAccCreditDate.DisplayDate = DateTime.Now.Date; --date is not displaying
cAccCreditDate.DisplayDate = DateTime.Now; -- date is not displaying
```

How to display a date, need code help

Comment: What do you mean by `Not Working`?

Comment: current date is not displaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the `SelectedDate` value.

```
cAccCreditDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add binding to DatePicker like this:

```
SelectedDate="{Binding DateToBind, Mode=TwoWay}
```

and then set value of DateToBind.

**UPD:**

Sample code (note: it's just a sample created in couple of minutes)

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DateTime _currentDateTime;
        public DateTime CurrentDateTime
        {
            get { return _currentDateTime; } 
            set { 
                _currentDateTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentDateTime");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Datetobind set value in c#..? I tried In c# Datetobind DateTime; Datetobind = DateTime.Now; , but not displaying, How to do this..